# Angular Proxy Config

Tags: angular, typescript

I have made the api call as below:

```
http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/login`);
```

This works well for all the builds (prod,stage,qa), when we build corresponding url is read.

How do i run it in the local server using proxy.config.json: I did as mentioned below which dint work:

```
{
  "${environment.apiUrl}/api/*": {
   "target": "https:serverIp/folder/",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Comment: by running do you mean running through ng or actually compiling and launching the JS output?

Comment: i want the api calls to work on ng serve

Comment: are you passing in the proxy config with the correct flag ?

Comment: How to set the proxy.config which replace ${environment.apiUrl}/api  to https://actualurl/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use string replacement tokens in a JSON file. Hardcode the path in the file.